# dataframe type lost after saving

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have the Dataframe I changed to category type. but after saving and loading the type returned to float64

```
data = pd.DataFrame(barray, columns=['line 1', 'line 2', 'line 3', 'line 4', 'piece to move', 'place to occupy'])
    data['possibility of win'] = y
    for col in ['line 1', 'line 2', 'line 3', 'line 4', 'piece to move', 'place to occupy']:
        data[col] = data[col].astype('category')

    data['line 1'].dtype
```

output:
CategoricalDtype(categories=['2000', '2001', '2002', '2010', '2011', '2012', '2020',
                  '2021', '2100', '2101', '2102', '2110', '2112', '2120',
                  '2121', '2200', '2201', '2202', '2210', '2211', '2212',
                  '2220', '2221'],
                 ordered=False)

```
data.to_csv('data.csv')
data = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
data['line 1'].dtype
```

output:
dtype('int64')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is expected, because in csv all data are saved like text.

Solution is add parameter `dtype` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
#all columns set to categoricals
data = pd.read_csv("data.csv", dtype='category')
```

If want specify only some columns use dictionary:

```
cols = ['line 1', 'line 2', 'line 3', 'line 4']
d = dict.fromkeys(cols, 'category')
data = pd.read_csv("data.csv", dtype=d)
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  It is possible to save the data like this or not

Comment: @Hacen Selahy In csv not, but I guess in pickle yes. Try `df. to_pickle(file)` and `pd. read_pickle(file)`